# Lookbehind using ggrep -P in bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep, gnu, lookbehind

I'm writing a bash script and I want to use a look behind in ggrep to find a specific value within a string.

While building a proof of concept example I'm able to return a result when using grep, but it's giving me the entire line rather than what's ahead of my designated lookbehind:

```
$echo "this and that 12 those" | ggrep -P '(?<=this\sand\sthat)[\s\d]+'

this and that 12 those
```

I was expecting to get `" 12 "` returned but instead got the entire line.

What am I missing here?

I'm using the following version of ggrep instealled using homebrew if that helps:

```
$ ggrep --version
ggrep (GNU grep) 2.14.56-1e3d
```

Comment: If this works like grep, try to add the `-o` option. `echo "this and that 12 those" | ggrep -o -P '(?<=this\sand\sthat)[\s\d]+'`

Comment: Perfect, that took care of it. Do you want to reply to this as the answer to the post so I can check it from my end?

Comment: @nico, post that as an answer

Comment: A note about lookbehinds: you cannot use variable width lookbehinds which is sometimes a pain. However Perl has a regex directive `\K` that accomplishes the same thing: it treats whatever is before the `\K` essentially as a lookbehind. This is illegal: `grep -oP '(?<=this.*that)[\s\d]+'` -- this is OK: `grep -oP 'this.*that\K[\s\d]+'`. [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions)

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks for the note re: variable widths in lookbacks using perl. I learned about that the hard way in a different stack overflow question I posted a while back, and it's a very good fact to note here for future searchers.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz My answer has been posted !

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `-o` option.

```
-o, --only-matching
              Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

The line becomes this :

`echo "this and that 12 those" | ggrep -o -P '(?<=this\sand\sthat)[\s\d]+'`